# Installing RHEL/CentOS over FTP using kickstart

Tags: virtualization, ftp, kickstart, virt-install

I have the following command to install CentOS using the virtual vsFTP server that I have at 192.168.122.1:

```
virt-install --name kickstart.example.com --ram 768 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/kickstart.example.com.img,size=12 \
--location ftp://192.168.122.1/pub/inst -x "ks=ftp://192.168.122.1/pub/ks.cfg"
```

The `ks.cfg` definitely exists because `wget 192.168.122.1/pub/ks.cfg` downloads the file.  I can navigate to `ftp://192.168.122.1/pub/ks.cfg` and see ny kickstart file.

The error I get is:

```
ERROR    Error validating install location: Could not find an installable 
distribution at 'ftp://192.168.122.1/pub/inst'
The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
```

Is it something to do with permissions or SELinux (SELinux is Enforcing).

ls -lZ on `192.168.122.1/pub/` and its subdirectories and kickstart file is this:

```
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 /var/ftp/pub/ks.cfg
```

Any ideas?  Many thanks :).

Comment: Just reading the error message, could we get a quick listing of `ftp://192.168.122.1/pub/inst`, preferably via FTP?  It's always possible that the error message means exactly what it says.

Comment: Does this - ftp://192.168.122.1/pub/inst - have valid directory structure? Do you have those metadata files valid?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. I am able to access the ftp location from a web browser over the network and over a different subnet. But virt-install always give a error while trying to read the ftp location path. Is this have some thing to do with the provding a network configration options along with virt-install ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the ISO images available as described in the [Preparing for a Network Installation section of the Installation guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-steps-network-installs-ppc.html#id3104847)?

The installer is not complaining about the kickstart file but about a missing installation tree.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you copied over the files from your source DVD, but missed the ".discinfo" file.  Kickstart will not recognize an installation source without this hidden file.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that `iptables` is not causing any problems. A simple way to check is to flush all settings by running:

```
iptables -F
```

If it runs after doing that, then you know it is due to an `iptables` setting.